# Trouble getting if statement to work in def, but not in interpreter

Tags: python, string, if-statement, function

When I run these commands in the interpreter I get the result I want.  However when I try to run it using a .py file I do not.  Im new to coding and in my brain I don't understand why this code does not work.

in the interpreter:

```
>>> a = 'This dinner is not that bad!'
>>> n = a.find('not')
>>> b = a.find('bad')
>>> if n < b:
      a.replace(a[n:], 'good')
'This dinner is good'
```

This is the result I want.

When I run this code I do not get the result I want.  What am I doing wrong, and why does this code not work?

```
def test(s):
  n = s.find('not')
  b = s.find('bad')

  if n < b:
    s.replace(s[n:], 'good')
print test('This dinner is not that bad!')
```

This is a exercise from the google intro to python course.  I have the correct answer from the example, and understand how that works.  Im just not sure why my code is not working.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

```
def test(s):
  n = s.find('not')
  b = s.find('bad')

  if n < b:
    return s.replace(s[n:], 'good')
print test('This dinner is not that bad!')
```

You should `return` the result from function `test`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks...I was just doing return s after the s.replace and it was giving me the same str.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Because in the function version, you will get `None` as default value, you didn't return the value :

```
def test(s):
  n = s.find('not')
  b = s.find('bad')
  return_res = ''

  if n < b:
    return_res = s.replace(s[n:], 'good')

  return return_res

print test('This dinner is not that bad!')
```

Output:

```
This dinner is good
```

Or not use `return_res`:

```
def test(s):
  n = s.find('not')
  b = s.find('bad')

  if n < b:
    return s.replace(s[n:], 'good')

  return "something else"

print test('This dinner is not that bad!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter in most (or all?) IDEs, if I'm not mistaken (I execute my code with Sublime, which saves and runs the file instead when executing), you get the result of your last expression printed automatically, giving you the false impression that python code behaves in this way. It doesn't.

So in other words: Your code works just the same in both the interpreter and the file. The problem you have is one of misconception, that the code is doing something different in the interpreter. What's really happening is that in neither code snippet do you actually *catch* the result and print it; in the case of the interpreter, it prints it automatically as kind of a visual aid, but you can't rely on that.

In your second snippet, you would have to write:

```
return s.replace(s[n:], 'good')
```

Notice the use of **return** in this case. In your first example, you *also* should be catching it or at least printing the result explicitly. But because it isn't enclosed in a function, the equivalent would be:

```
if n < b:
    print a.replace(a[n:], 'good')
```

or:

```
if n < b:
    newString = a.replace(a[n:], 'good')

print newString
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!  I see exactly what I was missing.  Thank you